# How to get input filename in multer with node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, multer

How can we get the name of the file that we are inputed when uploading files? I using multer on node.js and I want to store the filename in mysql db but I can't figure out how to get the filename.

```
var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'featured_img', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'audio', maxCount: 1 }]);
app.post('/save', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) { 
    let data = {featured_img: req.files.featured_img, title: req.body.title, band_name: req.body.band_name, audio: req.files.audio};
    let sql = "INSERT INTO music SET ?";
    let query = connection.query(sql, data,(err, results) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(data);
      res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed to go a couple of level deeper. As `req.files.featured_img` is the `object` data. you need to access the property `filename`. also consider that it is in an `ARRAY`, so you need to access `[0]` as well. Same goes with the `audio`

So it would be like this:

```
let data = {
             featured_img: req.files.featured_img[0].filename, 
             title: req.body.title, 
             band_name: req.body.band_name, 
             audio: req.files.audio[0].filename
            };
```

Just incase you need the location or the URL path as well, just do `req.files.featured_img[0].path` and `req.files.audio[0].path`

Comment: I got: sql: "INSERT INTO music SET `featured_img` = NULL, `title` = 'asdasd', `band_n
ame` = 'asdsasda', `audio` = NULL"

Comment: also tried req.files.featured_img.originalname but also null

Comment: can you `console.log(req.files.featured_img)` just to see whats in that

Comment: image above the result of that

Comment: same result image above

Comment: ive edited the answer you need access [0] since they are arrays

Comment: you mean featured_img[0].filename?

Comment: like `req.files.featured_img[0].filename`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219390/discussion-between-exe-and-karl-l).